# count nunique from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, counter

My goal is to add a column which counts the number of unique instances of a primary key in dfB using the keys in dfA. dfA has the primary key only show up once while dfB would have the primary key multiple times.

Example.

dfA

| Agreement | Date_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 146108493 | 1/31/2019 |
| 142527722 | 1/9/2019 |

dfB

| Agreement | Date_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 146108493 | 2/4/2019 |
| 146108493 | 2/15/2019 |
| 146108493 | 2/20/2019 |
| 142527722 | 2/28/2019 |
| 142527722 | 3/15/2019 |

Goal Outcome- adjusted dfA

| Agreement | Date_1 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 146108493 | 1/31/2019 | 3 |
| 142527722 | 1/9/2019 | 2 |

Answer (score 3):

You can `group` dataframe `dfB` on `Agreement` and aggregate using `count` then `map` the values to `dfA` based on primary key `Agreement`:

```
dfA['Count'] = dfA['Agreement'].map(dfB.groupby('Agreement')['Date_2'].count())
```

Or use `value_counts` with `map` as suggested by @Pygirl in comments:

```
dfA['Count'] = dfA['Agreement'].map(dfB['Agreement'].value_counts())
```

---

```
   Agreement     Date_1  Count
0  146108493  1/31/2019      3
1  142527722   1/9/2019      2
```

Comment: Nice catch @pygirl that's certainly a more concise option..

Comment: `dfa['count'] = dfa['Agreement'].map(dfb['Agreement'].value_counts())` if only considering instance count from agreement

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.merge`:

```
In [1161]: x = dfA.merge(dfB, indicator='Count').query('Count == "both"').groupby('Agreement').size().reset_index(name='Count')

In [1165]: dfA = dfA.merge(x)

In [1166]: dfA
Out[1166]: 
   Agreement     Date_1  Count
0  146108493  1/31/2019      3
1  142527722   1/9/2019      2
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
x = dfa.merge(dfb, on='Agreement', how='right')
y = x.groupby('Agreement').size().reset_index(name='Count')
dfa = dfa.merge(y, on='Agreement')
```

In one line:

```
dfa.join(dfb['Agreement'].groupby(dfb['Agreement']).count().rename('Count'), on='Agreement')
```

---

**dfa:**

```
    Agreement   Date_1  count
0   146108493   1/31/2019   3
1   142527722   1/9/2019    2
```

#### EDIT:

try filtering them using this function.

```
def grpdates(grp):
    stRow = grp.iloc[0]
    stRow1 = dfa[dfa['Agreement']==stRow.Agreement].Date_1
    grp = grp[np.array(grp.Date_2)<=np.array(stRow1 + pd.DateOffset(days=30))]
    return grp  

dfb['Date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(dfb.Date_2, format='%m/%d/%Y')
dfa['Date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa.Date_1, format='%m/%d/%Y')

df = dfb.groupby('Agreement', group_keys=False).apply(grpdates)
dfa['Count'] = dfa['Agreement'].map(df['Agreement'].value_counts())
```

---

**dfa:**

```
    Agreement   Date_1      Count
0   146108493   2019-01-31  3.0
1   142527722   2019-01-09  NaN
```

Comment: thanks for helping here. how would you add an additional filter to count agreement based on the date columns in the dataframes. example would be count how many of the dfA agreements show up in dfB within 30 days of dfA Date_1

Comment: Replace NaN by using `.fillna(0)`